# Vue Router duplicate header

Tags: vue-router, vuejs3

I'm working on a vue3 project.
The idea is to have a `main` component composed by a `header` and 2 view.
When someone click on the `h1` button I want to show the relative content under the header but `vue-router` keep duplicating the entire `main` component instead of only append the `h1` components content under the `header`

```js
/* main.ts */
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import main from './components/main.vue'
import h1 from './components/h1.vue'
import h2 from './components/h2.vue'

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: main,
    children: [
      { path: 'h1', component: h1 },
      { path: 'h2', component: h2 },
    ],
  },
]
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes,
})
createApp(App).use(router).mount('#app')
```

```html
<template>
<!-- main.vue  -->
  <div style="display:flex; flex-direction:column">
    <header>Header 
      <router-link to="h1" >h1</router-link> 
      <router-link to="h2" >h2</router-link>
    </header>
    <!-- Here ↓↓↓ I should see only the content from h1 -->
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>
```

```html
<template>
<!-- h1.vue  -->
<!-- h2 is the same with: Hi I'm H2 -->
  <div>
  Hi I'm H1 
  </div>
</template>
```

I hope that everything is clear.
To replicate the environment
`yarn create vite` or `npx create vite`
choose a `vue 3 template` then add `vue-router` as dependency.

Answer (score 0):

So, I've found that for what I need to do `vue-router` give you the option of using `router-view` and the `component(s)` option in route configuration to setup the layout.

Check out [named view](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-views.html#nested-named-views) @ router-vue docs for further info.